# Como ordenar uma lista de palavras fornecidas pelo usuário utilizando Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou tentando criar um programa em que o usuário informa a lista de palavras a colocar em ordem alfabética, só que quando eu colocava o programa pra rodar, ele funcionava normalmente, porém a lista que ele me dava estava listando letra por letra e citando as vírgulas e o espaços também, só que eu queria que ele listasse só as palavras ordenadas em forma de lista.
Vou deixar o script e a imagem do resultado aqui:

```
print('Digite as palavras desejadas para colocar em ordem alfabética.')
resposta = list(input())
resposta.sort()
print('Aqui está sua lista de palavras em ordem alfabética:')
print(resposta)
```

[image: Resultado do script]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é que, quando você passa uma string para o construtor `list`, todos os caracteres da string serão convertidos em *elementos individuais* da lista.

Você precisa, então, pegar a string (com a função [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input)), dividi-la por espaços para obter cada palavra e, enfim, sorteá-la.

Ficaria assim:

```
resposta = sorted(input().split(" "))
```

Aqui estamos, basicamente, pegando a resposta do usuário (com a função [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input)), dividindo a resposta pelos espaços utilizando o método [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str#str.split) (operação essa que já retorna uma lista) e, enfim, sorteando-a com a função [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted).

Em suma:

```
print('Digite as palavras desejadas para colocar em ordem alfabética.')

resposta = sorted(input().split(" "))

print('Aqui está sua lista de palavras em ordem alfabética:')
print(resposta)
```

---

Mas o problema com a abordagem acima é que ela não retorna somente as palavras. Se, por exemplo, passa-se como entrada "*Olá, como vai a sua vida?*", receberíamos:

```
['Olá,', 'a', 'como', 'sua', 'vai', 'vida?']
```

O que mostra que a classificação está funcionando corretamente, embora caracteres como a vírgula mantenham-se como parte de uma "palavra".

Para resolver isso, pode-se dividir a entrada fornecida por uma expressão regular. Assim:

```
import re

regex = re.compile("\W+", re.U)
resposta = sorted(filter(len, regex.split(input())))

print(resposta)
```

Desse modo, com a mesma entrada anterior, obteríamos:

```
['Olá', 'a', 'como', 'sua', 'vai', 'vida']
```

A diferença se dá porque estamos utilizando a expressão regular `\W+` para dividir a string fornecida pelo usuário, de modo que a string será dividida por qualquer caractere que não seja alfanumérico. Também foi utilizado `filter(len, <list>)` para remover "strings vazias" do *output*, o que pode ocorrer em alguns casos.

---

E, só para não deixar de falar — por padrão, `sorted` (evidentemente) diferencia letras em caixa alta ou baixa. Se você quiser ignorar esse comportamento na ordenação, pode passar o argumento nomeado `key` como `str.casefold`, que converte todas as letras para *lowercase*. Assim:

```
sorted(<list>, key=str.casefold)
```

É muita coisa, eu sei, mas detalhes são importantes. :-)

#### Referência

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/6314634/7445826
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/3845453/7445826
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/13209453/7445826
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/10269701/7445826

Comment: Obrigado por responder :)